# Why does WPF ignore this ToString() override? (F#)

Tags: wpf, string, mvvm, binding, f#

I have the following

```ml
type GivenName() =
    inherit VMBase()
    member this.First
        with get() = this.Get(<@ this.First @>, String.Empty)
    member this.Middle
        with get() = this.Get(<@ this.Middle @>, String.Empty)
    member this.Last
        with get() = this.Get(<@ this.Last @>, String.Empty)
    member this.Prefix
        with get() = this.Get(<@ this.Prefix @>, String.Empty)
    member this.Suffix
        with get() = this.Get(<@ this.Suffix @>, String.Empty)
    member this.FullName
        with get() = this.Get(<@ this.FullName @>, String.Empty)
        and set (value) = parseName value
    member this.Generation
        with get() = this.Get(<@ this.Generation @>, String.Empty)

    override this.ToString() = 
        this.FullName
```

Now in WPF, the first binding does not work, it produces nothing in my WPF Application. It only shows the text if I specify the "FullName" property in the binding path.

```
    <TextBox
        DataContext="{StaticResource ContactInformation}"
        Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/><!-- Does not Work -->
    <TextBox
        DataContext="{StaticResource ContactInformation}"
        Text="{Binding Name.FullName, Mode=OneWay}"/><!-- Works -->
```

Comment: What do you see? Default implementation of `ToString` or exception/binding error? I would expect you get binding error

Comment: Nothing. My TextBox is empty. I even added listeners using `PresentationTraceSources.DataBindingSource.Listeners.Add` with both Warning and Error. No binding errors.

Comment: Don't know much about F# but assuming that `Name` is of `GivenName` type it should work, at least it works in a small C# example that I've just created

Comment: Exactly what I'm experiencing. I can rewrite this in C# and it works. `ContactInformation.Name` is actually an explicitly cast GivenName to `IName` (an interface which GivenName implements, which includes all the same members, including the same ToString() override)

Comment: Did you try returning fixed text in `ToString`?

Comment: Good idea, but did not work. Replaced with "xzy". Placed a breakpoint on it and it never gets hit.

Comment: Can you provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: my attempts to reproduce your error was not a success

Comment: offtopic Q: why not just use FsXAML + FsVM?

Comment: Using FSharp.ViewModule everything works as expected. Can you provide a MCVE that reproduces the behaviour?